# Getting Value Error while using the Darts Module for Linear regression

Tags: time-series, darts

I am getting Value error while using the following code using Darts module -

```
series_targetCol=TimeSeries.from_series(df_PreprocessedDataSet['targetCol'])
y_train=series_targetCol
features=['feature1','feature2','feature3']
future_cov=TimeSeries.from_dataframe(df_PreprocessedDataSet[features])
model = RegressionModel(lags=[-1,-2,-12],
                        model=LinearRegression(),
                        lags_future_covariates=[0]
                        )
model.fit(series=y_train,future_covariates=future_cov)
y_pred=model.predict(n=1,series=y_train,future_covariates=future_cov)
y_pred=pd.DataFrame(TimeSeries.pd_dataframe(y_pred))
```

Here is the error -

```
ValueError: The corresponding future_covariate of the series at index 0 isn't sufficiently long. Given horizon `n=1`, `min(lags_future_covariates)=0`, `max(lags_future_covariates)=0` and `output_chunk_length=1`, the future_covariate has to range from 26 until 26 (inclusive), but it ranges only from 0 until 25.
```